# PHP на веб-сервере Java

Tags: php, java, сокет, websocket, веб-сервер

Можно ли реализовать веб-сервер так, чтобы страницы обрабатывались при помощи языка PHP, а `ServerSocket` был запущен на Java? То есть что-то вроде следующего:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class Main {

    static ServerSocket i1;

    public static void main(String[] i2) {
        try {
            i1 = new ServerSocket(80);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Socket i2 = i1.accept();
                            // Ответить клиенту веб-сервера нужно главной страницой
                            // Для этого откроем этот файл "index.php"
                            BufferedReader i3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("index.php")));
                            String i4 = "";
                            while (true) {
                                String i5 = i3.readLine();
                                if (i5 == null) {
                                    i3.close();
                                    break;
                                } else {
                                    i4 += i5 + System.lineSeparator();
                                }
                            }
                            /*
                            Пусть содержимое файла "index.php" будет следующим:
                                    <?php
                                    echo 'Hello world!';
                                    ?>

                            Его нужно обработать в PHP обработчике примерно так:
                                    i4 = i4.обработать_в_PHP();

                            И, затем, если сделать вывод "System.out.println(i4)", должно быть выведено следующее:

                                    Hello world!

                            И, в итоге клиент должен получить строчку "Hello world!":
                            */
                            i2.getOutputStream().write(i4.getBytes());
                            i2.getOutputStream().close();
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Теоретически да, но просто написать на Java рациональнее.

Answer (score 2):

В java есть Java Scripting API (JSR 223), который позволяет исполнять скрипты 'внутри java'. Можно сделать свою реализацию для PHP или использовать, например [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/how_it_works.php).

Кроме того, есть Quercus - реализация PHP движка на java для серверa Resin

Answer (score 1):

Наверняка из джавовского сервера можно пропроксировать запросы на PHP-FPM через CGI протокол. Но если тебе нужно рендерить только один php файл (ну или у тебя точка входа в страницу через один файл), то можно из джавы запустить системную команду:

```
php index.php
```

stdout и stderr этой команды и будет твоя "страница, отрендеренная на php".
Проблема здесь будет в том, что php не будет знать ничего о параметрах запроса (кукисы, заголовки и тп)

http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.ru/2008/06/java-run-system-command-and-return.html

Comment: Значит сессии реализовать тоже нельзя будет? Очень жаль. Они нужны.

Comment: Можно но вручную и с приседаниями в джаве. Если правильно проксировать на FPM будешь, то там сессии автоматом будут держаться.

Comment: Еще можешь из самой джавы пропроксировать запрос на 81 порт, а на 81 порт повесить php со встроенным веб-сервером:

php -S localhost:81 index.php

По-моему самый простой вариант, который должен сработать

Comment: Я не понимаю. Можете поподробнее объяснить как реализовать сессии.

Comment: Парсить в джаве HTTP протокол, выдирать заголовки и подсовывать их в index.php, опять же, в ручную, например через параметры:
php index.php header11=... header2=... и тп, а в самом пхп получать их через $argv.

Comment: Я скачал архив PHP.zip и переместил из него файлы в D:\PHP\. Как правильно вызвать PHP через командную строку, чтобы InputStream командной строки вернул мне обработанную страницу?

Answer (score -2):

Запустить php-fpm, а потом используя протокол FastCGI передать туда параметры запроса и скрипт для выполнения.

Что -то типа: https://github.com/Happyr/fcgi4j